# Payment received with old wallet not shown in new one

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-forks

I was mining (slowly) on xmrpool.eu since 2017 and finally received a payment. The problem is that when I open my wallet with the GUI, it doesn't show the address I was mining with neither the payment.

How can I solve it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you do not simply have a different wallet open in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a payment id with your address which could be why you might not see the same address. To verify you can tell if the address is an integrated payment id, by see if the address looks similar. If it is, then you have it in your wallet. Also make sure you have your wallet fully synced too.